# how to resolve AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am recently getting
**AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException** in my project. I did not change anything related to auto mapper. Moreover the exception count is drastically increasing exactly after 30 days and the application is completely down. My application is hosted on azure and when we replay the function in web job the application behavior is normal. Please share your views and thoughts so that I can resolve this issue.
Below is the exact exception

**Trying to map ServiceAutoDetailsViewDto to ServiceAutoDto.
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.**

Sometimes I am getting below exception as well

**System.InvalidOperationException at AutoMapper.Configuration.FindTypeMap**

Comment: It would be helpful to see your DTOs and the mapping that is configured for them.

Comment: Thanks Maxim. But from DTO side we did not change anything. Earlier it used to work. But dont know suddenly it is giving errors without any new code changes